# Results of code execution appear out of order

Tags: java, netbeans

I intend for a user to press a button, which executes the following procedure:

1. display message "function fitting in progress..." in a log (`jTextField`);
2. run some heavy calculations for the function fitting;
3. after the calculations are complete, write in the log "function fitting is complete".

What actually happens:

1. after the button press  the calculations begin immediately;
2. after the calculations are complete both "..in progress..." and "..complete" messages are displayed in the log simultaneously;

Attempted solution to solve issue:

I've tried adding time delay (`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);`) between the 1st and the 2nd actions, the result is the same.

Implemented code is as follows:

```
private void jButton33ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    add_to_log("function fitting in progress...");
    FunctionFitter3step FF3step  = new FunctionFitter3step(/*variables for the constructor, which does all the heavy calculations*/);
    add_to_log("function fitting complete!");
}


void add_to_log (String input_string){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    this.log_string = this.log_string + " [" + dtf.format(now) + "] " + input_string + "\n";
    This.jTextField_program_log.setText(this.log_string);
}
```

Comment: hello , the function add_to_log are asynchrone ?

Comment: I think that you need to use a different thread to execute your calculations https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: im not sure. what does "asynchrone" means in this context, but i added the add_to_log function in the question. @RubioRic thanks for linking the tutorial, gonna read it right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FunctionFitter3step` is clearly being run asynchronously. You need to use some kind of callback. Here's one way:

- Add a `Runnable` parameter to the parameter list of `FunctionFitter3step`
- Wrap the log statement as a `Runnable`
- Have your `FunctionFitter3step` code call `runnable.run()` as its last step

Assuming Java 8:

```
FunctionFitter3step FF3step  = new FunctionFitter3step(/*variables*/, () -> add_to_log("function fitting complete!"));
```

Comment: took me a while to figure out what all of that means, but eventually i did it and it works great, thanks!